# upload image and make watermark

Tags: php, watermark

```
private function upload($name, $types){
        for($i = 0; $i < count($name); $i++){
            move_uploaded_file($types[$i], $this->_direction . $name[$i]);
            $this->waterMark($name[$i]);
        }
    }
```

this function uploads photo and it works.
but this watermark function is not works :(

```
private function waterMark($imgs){
        $stamp = imagecreatefrompng('http://localhost/public_html/img/watermark.png');
        $im = imagecreatefromjpeg('http://localhost/public_html/uploaded/' . $imgs);

        $marge_right = 10;
        $marge_bottom = 10;
        $sx = imagesx($stamp);
        $sy = imagesy($stamp);

        imagecopy($im, $stamp, imagesx($im) - $sx - $marge_right, imagesy($im) - $sy - $marge_bottom, 0, 0, imagesx($stamp), imagesy($stamp));

        header('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($im);
        imagedestroy($im);
    }
```

What mistake have I ?

Comment: Use Directory path.. your image paths are looking like mix-up.. Directory path doesn't have `http://localhost/`.. Please check both path of images..

Comment: I changed it with:
$stamp = imagecreatefrompng('public_html/img/watermark.png');
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg('public_html/uploaded/' . $imgs);

but still doesn't work

Comment: please remove `public_html` and check.. If result will stay same, please let me know your folder structure.!!

Comment: It need public_html. 
I have Mvc and in Public_html folder I've imgs/css/js/uploaded folders. 

I make submit with ajax  and response is: http://oi62.tinypic.com/5mza0w.jpg [SCREEN]

What is this? Thanks in advance

Comment: it's an image's raw out put.. if you try to open any image in text editor, it'll look like this.. ok.. are you saving image or displaying directly? if saving, use `imagepng($im, $img_path);`

Comment: yes you are true, I'm not saving image.

imagepng($im, 'public_html/uploaded');
now I make this. but I've another error:

Message:  imagepng(public_html/uploaded): failed to open stream: Permission denied

I write chmod("public_html/uploaded", 0777);

but still doesn't work

Comment: that's good..!! Please write answer and make it solution.. so in future any user has same issue can find here!!